# A vector field with specified curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

I need a vector field $\vec{F}:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that 
$$\mathrm{curl}\ \vec{F}(x,y,z) \cdot \left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}},\ 0,\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) = 1.$$
(This equality, of course, holds if $\mathrm{curl}\ F(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}},\ 0,\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$. But this is not necessarily the case.) Can somebody help me?

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? Do you want **all** such vector fields or just **one**? At the first glance, this problem shouldn't have a unique solution. :)

Comment: I wanted just one. Now, this is no more urgent. My intention was elaborating a question of Calculus for testing knowledge on area of surfaces and Stokes theorem, at once.

Comment: Now I have verified that the vector field $(-x, 0, 1)/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ cannot be the curl of another vector field, since its divergence is not zero.